# covert json file to .tde file using tableau extract api in java

Tags: java, json, tableau-api

I am new to tableau and java. I have a json file which I am fetching from the hive and have to convert it into tableau extract as tableau server's input.I have checked the web for options available for the same and came across an option tableau extract API which converts the different formats to tde format. But how it works, didn't find anything else like how it came be used in java.

Can anyone suggest something?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your data structure it should possible to convert you JASON to a flat structure. You can try using `ObjectMapper` class from Jackson library.

After that you can use Tableau SDK for Java to create your '.tde' file.
You can download the Tableau SDK for Java from [here](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/api/sdk/en-us/SDK/tableau_sdk_installing.htm#downloading).

The downloaded ZIP has Java sample code 'TableauSDKSample.java' to get you started.

Comment: when i try to execute the sample java code, it is throwing the following error, "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'DataExtract': The specified module could not be found."

Comment: Could be a problem with build path. The java file needs to refer to the .jar files from Tableau SDK. Try following the steps here: 
 [link](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/api/sdk/en-us/help.htm#SDK/tableau_sdk_using_java_eclipse.htm%3FTocPath%3D_____5)

Comment: i dont have tableaucommon.jar file. Also, i have placed the tableauextract.jar and jna.jar in the sdk extract path/java folder...is it the right path?